# Publish remote server [Win32Exception (0x80004005)]

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm wondering if my connection string is wrong because when I publish this on a server it doesn't work, otherwise when I test it on debug mode it works.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-app-20130122205025;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-app-20130122205025.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SiteSourceContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=SiteSourceContext-20130125171153; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|SiteSourceContext-20130125171153.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can someone help out? Im relatively new and trying to learn, so I dont know what Im doing but this is the error I get:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified file is not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related error or instance-specific occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Could not locate installation of a runtime database locally. Verify that SQL Server Express is installed and the runtime functionality of local database is enabled.) ]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError (SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action `1 wrapCloseInAction) 6675286
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning (TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) 688
```

Comment: does the application accessing the database have the database copied as part of the application? looks to me like it cannot find the database because it is either not there or simply isn't visible to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that SQL Server Express is installed and the runtime functionality of local database is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing This :

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0
```

To This :

```
Data Source=.\v11.0
```

Or This :

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress
```

Comment: I did this and still doesnt work :/. Does Microsoft Entity Framework install the SQL Database when you publish it, or do you have to manually install it on the remote location as well?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that using `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0` limits the credentials to the user that created/owns the database.  If you are publishing this as an ASP.NET service, your code will be running under a different user; likely NETWORK SERVICE.

Further, it looks like the connection string is specifying a file that probably only exists in your development environment, not on the server you are publishing to. **You'll need to install SQLExpress on that server** and set up the connection string to access that. I wouldn't use `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;`; instead I'd use `Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;` or `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` to maintain consistency between your development environment and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the instance name of SQL server installed in your development computer and server have different names. So you need to change the connection string. If you have installed SQL Server, if not you need to install it.

Other possibility is, the instance of the SQL Server might not be running. You can go to Windows Services from control panel and check if SQL Server service you stored your database started or not. There might be multiple services, if you have multiple instances of SQL Server. Make sure that you are using the connection string for the correct instance.

Also, in your database, you should give access priority to related IIS user (e.g. IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool), if you decide to use Windows Authentication. Or you can use SQL Server authentication.

In a nutshell, I believe that you have problem with referring to SQL Server Instance. When you solve it, if you do not try to access to DB with valid credentials, you will have a authentication problem.